# Создать в R табличку в которой вместо нумеров строк и столбцов названия

Tags: r

Как для объектов `table` и `data.frame` изменить/установить имена столбцов и/или строк?

Например, так:

```
        Result
Drugs    negative   positive
drug_1 -2.0663666  2.0663666
drug_2  1.1561265 -1.1561265
drug_3  0.6446097 -0.6446097
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этого можно достичь с помощью следующих операторов: `dimnames<-`, `rownames<-`, `colnames<-`.

Имейте в виду, что поведение этих функций отличается для матриц и дата фреймов.

```r
d <- data.frame(
  negative = c(-2.0663666, 1.1561265, 0.6446097),
  positive = c(2.0663666, -1.1561265, -0.6446097)
)
m <- as.matrix(d)
nm <- list(
  "Drugs" = c("drug_1", "drug_2", "drug_3"),
  "Result" = c("negative", "positive")
)
dimnames(d) <- nm
dimnames(m) <- nm
```

```r
> print(d)
         negative   positive
drug_1 -2.0663666  2.0663666
drug_2  1.1561265 -1.1561265
drug_3  0.6446097 -0.6446097
> print(m)
        Result
Drugs      negative   positive
  drug_1 -2.0663666  2.0663666
  drug_2  1.1561265 -1.1561265
  drug_3  0.6446097 -0.6446097
```

Вместо явного перечисления всех строк (`c("drug_1", "drug_2", "drug_3")`) эффективнее сгенерировать их. Например, вот так:

```r
paste0("drug_", seq_len(nrow(d)))
```